# AWS Codeartifact npm private repository fail to download dependencies

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, aws-codeartifact

I have this situation:

- I created a npm package and deployed it into AWS CodeArtifact.  This artifact depends of `aws-sdk` package.
- When I tried to use the new packege from other project, fallowing carefully what AWS docs says in [Publishing private npm packages with AWS CodeArtifact](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/publishing-private-npm-packages-aws-codeartifact/), I got the error trace:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://my-domain-###########.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/npm/MyRepo/aws-sdk - Package, 'aws-sdk', not found.
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'aws-sdk@^2.1048.0' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

Do you know what I do have to change to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I could solve this issue. The solution is simple. I had to edit `MyRepo` and associate an `Upstream repository` to `npm-store`.

Answer (score 0):

> I had to edit MyRepo and associate an Upstream repository to npm-store.

Associated upstream repositories are optional; it says so right in the console. It is possible to install a package that is published *only* on AWS CodeArtifact. That one of the value propositions of this service: You are not limited to publishing a package, (public or private), on npmjs.com.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your modules npm registry links were updated by the "aws codeartifact login" command. You can use scoped registry update in place of this. In such situation, just the scoped package is using the new registry. You can turn this on directly in the aws command by providing '--namespace' parameter. For eg:

> aws codeartifact login --tool npm --repository my-repo --domain my-domain --namespace @myscope

Your package would look like this in this case: @myscope/my-repo

Here is the registry link for all other packages: https://registry.npmjs.org/

Answer (score 0):

[RDV's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70832384/8631265) is good and helped me, Thanks

I want to add explanation how to **Associate an Upstream repository to npm-store.**

Follow those instrunction from [aws](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codeartifact/latest/ug/repo-upstream-add.html):

> **To add an upstream repository using the CodeArtifact console:**
>
> - Open the AWS CodeArtifact console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/codesuite/codeartifact/home.
> - In the navigation pane, choose Domains, and then choose the domain
>   name that contains your repository.
> - Choose the name of your repository.
> - Choose Edit.
> - In Upstream repositories, choose Associate upstream repository  and add
>   the repository you want to add as an upstream repository. **(in this case only select npm-store)** You can only
>   add repositories in the same domain as upstream repositories.
> - Choose Update repository.

[image]